# Mongoid::Criteria.only(:name) returns all fields nil except name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

When I run `User.only(:name).all` or whatever variant of that query, I get:

```
[#<User _id: 52003fb8487874985b
000003, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, role_ids: nil, name: "Tom Amfeagfhbdge Bowersman", usernam
e: nil, fb_id: nil, fb_token: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, reset_password_token: nil, r
eset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, l
ast_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>,  
 #<User _id: 5200405a487874fb550
00004, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, role_ids: nil, name: "Carol Amfdheibbjbf Sadanwitz", userna
me: nil, fb_id: nil, fb_token: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, reset_password_token: nil,
reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil,
last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>,  
 #<User _id: 520040d14878746fe5
000005, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, role_ids: nil, name: "Tom Amfdidheeidd Yangson", username:
 nil, fb_id: nil, fb_token: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, reset_password_token: nil, res
et_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, las
t_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>]
```

All the fields in my document return with a nil value except the parameter for the only function.

I want to get the result something kind of like this:

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": "5008484"
  },
  {
    "id": "47402727"
  },
  {
    "id": "500154435"
  },
  {
    "id": "500598450"
  },
  {
    "id": "500655911"
  },
  {
    "id": "500666528"
  },
  {
    "id": "500700148"
  },
  {
    "id": "500973616"
  },
  {
    "id": "501130485"
  },
  {
    "id": "501254060"
  }]
```

Instead of "id", "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i have found so far is using the Mongo driver directly.

`Mongo::MongoClient.new(ENV['MONGOID_HOST'], ENV['MONGOID_PORT']).db(ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE']).collection('friends').find({}, {fb_id: 1})`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

{data: User.only(:name).all.map(&:attributes)}